# Fresh laravel installation without User related controllers

Tags: laravel

How can I create fresh laravel project without user-related controllers OR How can I completely and safely drop all things related to it?

[image: Laravel Fresh Installation - Directory Structure]

Comment: It won't break anything if you just delete the `Auth` controllers folder.

Comment: @RossWilson is there anything else to remove?

Comment: You could also remove the user and password_reset migrations, the database factory for the user,  the `User` model etc. All that being said, as long as you don't use any of the `auth` functions in Laravel and you don't include the `auth` routes then you shouldn't notice anything anyway.